# Oracle SQL - join table in one-to-many relationship, but instead of duplicating rows show min/max

Tags: sql, database, oracle

let's say I have `TRADE` table and `TRADE_EXECUTION` table. Common link between them is `TRADE_ID`.

`TRADE_EXECUTION` has all broker executions which are part of final `TRADE` (so information about executed quantity, timestamp of execution etc.). This means that for each entry in `TRADE` table there might be multiple, one or no corresponding rows in `TRADE_EXECUTION`.

So if I do standard `LEFT JOIN` rows from `TRADE` will be duplicated in case there are multiple corresponding entries in `TRADE_ATTRIBUTES`.

Instead of duplicating rows I want to show in my `SELECT` query columns `TRADE_ID`, `MIN(EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP)` and `MAX(EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP)` for each entry from `TRADE` table.

So if there are 5 executions pointing to one trade I want to show earliest and latest execution timestamp from them and put in one row instead of showing 5 rows.

I need to also keep in mind that TRADE_EXECUTION table is quite big (200k records added daily, around 50m in total so far).

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Sounds like a simple aggregation query with `GROUP BY`..

Comment: next time instead of trying to describe your problem put sample data. It will be faster for us to point out issue and guide you through process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
select t.*, min_executiontimestamp, max_executiontimestamp
from trade t left join
     (select te.trade_id, min(executiontimestamp) as min_executiontimestamp,
             max(executiontimestamp) as max_executiontimestamp
      from trade_execution te
      group by te.trade_id
     ) te
     on te.trade_id = t.trade_id;
```

This allows you to select all the columns you want from `trade`, without fiddling with a `group by` clause.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to avoid GROUP BY in main SELECT. One more question - what if I want to add count of executions corresponding to trade as another column?

Comment: @Radek . . . You would put a `count(*) in the subquery and then use column that in the outer select.

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join with aggregation should do, as in:

```
select
  t.trade_id,
  MIN(e.EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP) as min_ts,
  MAX(e.EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP) as max_ts
from trade t
left join trade_execution e on e.trade_id = t.trade_id
group by t.trade_id
```

Comment: Can I add multiple other parameters to that SELECT query from TRADE? or since you did GROUP BY I cant put anything else in SELECT?

Comment: Yes, you can add more columns to the select. However, the columns in the `GROUP BY` can be added directly **without aggregation**; the columns not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` **must be aggregated**: any aggregation function will do, such as min(), max(), sum(), avg(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  TRADE_ID,
  MAX(EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP) MAX_TS,
  MIN(EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP) MIN_TS
FROM
  TRADE
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRADE_EXECUTION 
  ON TRADE.ID = TRADE_EXECUTION.ID
WHERE /* PUT YOUR WHERE CONDITIONS IF THERE IS*/
GROUP BY TRADE_ID;
```

Please note that since your table has very high volume of records, you need to use your where condition wisely. You need to filter your data using indexed columns

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH exec AS 
(SELECT TRADE_ID, MIN(TRADE_EXECUTION) MIN_EXEC, MAX(TRADE_EXECUTION) MAX_EXEC
FROM TRADE_EXECUTION
GROUP BY TRADE_ID)
SELECT t.TRADE_ID, e.MIN_EXEC, e.MAX_EXEC
FROM TRADE t LEFT JOIN exec e ON t.TRADE_ID=e.TRADE_ID;
```

And add as much TRADE columns as you need without grouping them....